# Apache Commons Client can't connect to AOL anymore

Tags: java

I am now unable to connect to AOL (using Windows 10 / Apache Commons Email Client 1.4, Java 9) having previously been successful. I did introduce a bug which meant I sent the password as 'null' and it seemed to happen after this (during March 2018). Would this cause the issue and, if so, is there anything I can do about it? If not, is there anything else that could cause the problem? I believe the following is the relevant code (excluding the other assignments):

```
SimpleEmail email = new    SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.aol.com"); 
email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("userid", "pwd"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.send();
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Could AOL have put some kind of block in place if you were continually trying to log in with invalid credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suspect that is the case. My code works ok for gmail. I was hoping someone would confirm that there is a block and might know how I can remove the block

Comment: Michael:sorry for the delay on this; the error message was:Sending the email to the following server failed: smtp.aol.com:465 and debugging gave this: DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.aol.com", port 465, isSSL false

Comment: Sorry: got names wrong: for Michael read alex440; haven't used Stackoverflow before and possibly focusing more on how to ask questions rather than the content (not really an excuse)

Comment: AOL have said that they will investigate the issue at some point. The blank password may be a red herring in that googlemail was rejecting my posts until I allowed my account to accept less secure accesses. I am assuming this is a certificate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end AOL appeared to be complaining about a lack of signature: I signed my jar file using: jarsigner –storepass mypwd –keypass mypwd myfile.jar
This worked for AOL but gmail still needed me to allow less secure applications to access my account. I shall presumably need a Trusted SSL certificate for that.